# Cakephp blog tutoria- comments section for individual articles

Tags: jquery, database, cakephp, show-hide

I'm new to cakephp and recently finished the blog tutorial, now I thought about having a comments section for it. I was succesful in that part. Below is my controller.

**Controller**

```
public function add_comment() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $this->Comment->create();
            if ($this->Comment->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your comment has been saved.'));
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 
                                      'action' => 'index', 
                                      'admin' => false));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
echo "<h1>Comments </h1>";

foreach ($post['Comment'] as $key => $the) {

echo"<div id='comment-{$post['Comment'][$key]['id']}'>";
echo "Name: ", $the['name'], '<br>';
echo "Comment: ", '<br />', $the['comment'], '<br>';
echo '</div>';
```

Adding and displaying the comment was a success. Here's the part where I'm stucked in.the code below is the continuation of the view. What it does is it renders two buttons, show and hide.

```
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
    echo $this->Form->button('Show', 
             array('type' => 'button',
                   'class' => 'show_comment',
                   'data-id' => $post['Comment'][$key]['id'],
                    ));

    echo $this->Form->button('Hide', 
             array('type' => 'button',
                   'class' => 'hide_comment',
                   'data-id' => $post['Comment'][$key]['id'],
                   ));
}
```

**main.js** - below is the jquery function that hides/show the comments on click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hide_comment").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log($(this).data('id'));
        $('#comment-' + id).hide();
    });

    $(".show_comment").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        console.log($(this).data('id'));
        $('#comment-' + id).show();
    });
});
```

what I'm trying to achieve is, when the admin is logged in he can hide or show the comments?,however once the page is reloaded/refreshed the hidden comments are showed once again. How can I make the hidden comments stay hidden until I click the show button. This is my approach in hiding/showing the comments, but I am very open to your suggestions. and is very much in need of your help thank you

Comment: Do you what to hide the comments to the admin/user when the admin hides it ?

Comment: the comments when hide by admin are not shown to the users who visit the site

Comment: there are ways to do it using jquery, what when you do it using jquery will load all the time, my solution to your problem is update some value('1' or '0')  for the comment in the database when the admin hides it. Anyways you will get the comment to show from db, that time you can hide it using the value from db for the comment.

Comment: on hide_comment click update the value in the db.

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand what you said, but the comments when submit has a default status(1) value, which I'm planning to use to indicate whether it is hidden or shown however, I'm not sure how to do it. maybe some samples might help?

Comment: `$this->ModelName->updateAll(array('status'=>0),array('Modelname.comment_id'=>1));` you can use this to update you db when hide button is clicked

Comment: have you got what you need or need more examples ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a field in your table and determine if comments are hidden or not.
For example, supposing the field you just entered is 'hidden' type bool, your Comments search should be:

```
$comments = $this->Comment->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Comment.hidden' => false
    )
)
```

With that condition the hidden comments will not be shown.
You may add two functions to hide and show your comments too and request em by ajax.

```
public function comment_show($id = null) {

    if ($this->request->is('ajax') {

        $this->Comment->id = $id;
        $this->Comment->saveField('hidden', false);

    }

}

public function comment_hide($id = null) {

    if ($this->request->is('ajax') {

        $this->Comment->id = $id;
        $this->Comment->saveField('hidden',true);

    }

}
```

Take in mind it`s just a illustration, without validation, access level check, etc.